# How to go to the top of the page after clicking the link?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

The problem is, it goes to the middle of the page whenever I navigate to a link in `NextJS`:

```
<Link href={`/products/${id}`} key={id}>
   <a>
      {/* other components */}
   </a>
</Link>
```

So i think the problem is that the link is on the middle of the page so when i click on the link it stays on the same position as where u clicked the link and not go at the top of the page. I know it doesn't make sense.

I tried adding things like `scroll={true}`, or `scroll={false}` to the `<Link>`. Tried adding `height: 100%` to **html** and **body** in `CSS`. I tried adding `scroll-behavior: smooth;` and other stuff. The problem still stays.

Heres the video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CCgFCJb1fl9RRYmW5yp41US-0yuSqpfj/view?usp=sharing

Temporary Solution:
its to not use Link and just use the usual `<a>` tag. Because `<Link>` don't make the page **reload** whilst `<a>` tag reloads the page when navigating to another page. so if the page reloads when you click the link then it always starts at the top.

Note: i tried all the solutions below.

Comment: No im using next/link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your page component, inside `useEffect` hook, put `window.scrollTo(0,0)`

```
useEffect(()=>{
  window.scrollTo(0,0);
},[])
```

Comment: im sorry can you clarify more about this? i personally know what it does but it doesn't work and I'm asking how is it gonna affect the link.

Comment: The Link must be pointing to one of the page in your app, So i'm suggesting to put inside useEffect of that page component, so that whenever the page renders for the first time, scroll is positioned at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set scrollRestoration in some root component.

```
 history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
```

Comment: To be honest, This gave me history is undefined error, so I added some code like this:

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    window.history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
  }

But it still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I found this article on web, you can try this: [link](https://mmazzarolo.com/blog/2021-04-10-nextjs-scroll-restoration/)

Comment: funny, because i actually saw that article aswell lol, sadly still wont work, my temporary solution was not using Link and just use the usual a tag. Because <Link> don't make the page reload whilst <a> tag reloads the page when navigating to another page. so if the page reloads when you click the link then it always starts at the top.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this hook and put id as it's dependency

```
useEffect(() => {
   window.scrollTo({
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          behavior: "smooth"
        });
}, [id])
```

if you use it in nextjs, you need to put an if condition in this way

```
useEffect(() => {

if(typeof window !== 'undefined'){
   window.scrollTo({
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          behavior: "smooth"
        });
   }
}, [id])
```